# PHP MYSQL MINUS operator

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать элементарный запрос:

```
"SELECT count(id) FROM votes  MINUS SELECT count(id) FROM votes"
```

Но появляется ошибка `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: SafeMySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Что не так?

Comment: вы вообще этим запросом чего хотите добиться то?

Comment: @teran этот запрос просто для примера, так как у меня не получается выполнить ни один запрос с оператором MINUS

Comment: в любом случае mysql не поддерживает `minus/except` операторы. то же самое можно реализовать через джойн. однако применительно к вашей структуре запроса,  не совсем ясно. чего вы таки пытаетесь добиться

Comment: @teran вообще мне не нужно ничего сложного, я хотел сделать следующее: получить количество id from votes where display = 1 и отнять от этого числа, количество тех же votes, только where display = 0.

Comment: дак `minus` это ведь не арифметический оператор. это инструкция для наборов данных. для ваших целей можно воспользоваться другими вариантами решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> получить количество id from votes where display = 1 и отнять от этого числа, количество тех же votes, только where display = 0

```
SELECT SUM(display = 1) - SUM(display = 0) AS result
FROM votes
```

Это в предположении, что поле ID - уникальное. Если нет, то

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN display = 1 THEN ID END) - COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN display = 0 THEN ID END) AS result
FROM votes
```