# Стоит ли так рефакторить? Замена условий на простые математические формулы

Tags: php, рефакторинг

Периодически делаю мелкий рефакторинг своего кода над текущим проектом, я раньше вообще не занимался этим и только начинаю изучать это дело. Вот хочу привести пример элементарного кода, который я захотел сделать еще более "элементарным", как мне кажется

Есть таблица `Orders`, состоящая из `id, user_id, created_at, type, value, status`, в данном примере нас интересуют только поля `value` и `type`. `value` - любое целочисленное положительное число, `type` - либо 0, либо 1 (0 - списание, 1 - начисление)

И собсно простой метод getPoints в классе User, который подсчитывает количество доступных очков пользователя

```
public function getPoints() {
        $return = 0;
        foreach (Order::findAll(['user_id'=> $this->id, 'status' => 1]) as $k => $value) {
            if ($value['type'] == 0)
                $return -= $value['value'];
            if ($value['type'] == 1)
                $return += $value['value'];
        }
        return $return;
}
```

От нечего делать я решил его немного изменить

```
public function getPoints() {
        $return = 0;
        foreach (Order::findAll(['user_id'=> $this->id, 'status' => 1]) as $value)
                $return += (-1 + 2*(int)$value['type'])*$value['value']; //$value['type'] равно либо 0, либо 1. 0 - вычитание, 1 - сумма. Формула -1 + 2*$value['type'] нужна для сокращения кода -1 + 2*0 = -1 -1 + 2*1 = 1

        return $return;
    }
```

То есть по сути просто избавился от условий и заменил это дело формулой (предполагается, что значения 0 и 1 никогда не будут меняться). Так вообще нормально делать? Стоит ли?

Comment: массу способов вроде придумать можно, и надо было выбрать настолько сложный? `$return += ($type == 1 ? $value : -$value)`

Comment: либо там `$k = [-1, 1]` и `+= $k[$type] * $value`

Comment: но если честно, такие штуки надо просто считать на стороне БД, примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774879/223826

Comment: @teran во, вот за это отдельное спасибо, про отдельный запрос как-то не подумал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уже "рефакторить", то где то так

```
public function getPoints() {
        $return = 0;
        foreach (Order::findAll(['user_id'=> $this->id, 'status' => 1]) as $k => $value) {
            $type = $value['type'];
            $val = $value['value'];
            if ($type == 0) {
                $return -= $val;
            else if ($type == 1) {
                $return += $val;
            } else {
              # а тут добавить вывод в лог, может что то пошло не так
            }
        }
        return $return;
}
```

Comment: а если бы нужно было обрабатывать 10 полей $value, а не 2?

Comment: меня просто эти строчки смутили,`$type = $value['type'];
            $val = $value['value'];` неужели они добавляют "читаемость"?

Comment: @Peresada именно они и добавляют, замечу что у меня в комментах к вопросу, так же написано :)

Comment: Да, они сильно добавляют, так как возле них можно поставить комментарий. А бывает, что в базе поле переименовали...  Если же полей 10, то тут нужно подумать, может они не нужны или нужно сделать себе класс-обертку.

Answer (score 5):

Такие сокращения не всегда есть хорошо, первый вариант гораздо быстрее и удобнее прочитать, и потратить меньше времени на то, что бы разобраться в логике.

P.S. По этому поводу на харбе недавно хорошая статья вышла: https://habrahabr.ru/post/347166/